# One-To-One with only one entity and 'linking' table NestJS and TypeORM

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I'm learning NestJS by building a sample application, and have created an `Item` entity with various properties, all set up in PostgreSQL by TypeORM, etc.

My question comes in that I want an attribute for `Item`s that not every `Item` will have. For instance, I want to add a `Scale` property, which can be one of 4 set values. To achieve this I would normally set up an Enum in NestJS that is an ID => Name set up. Then would have a `scale_id` value on the `Item`. Since not every `Item` will have a `Scale` I want to use a 'linking' table with an `item_id` and a `scale_id`.

Ultimately I want to be able to query `item`s by `scale_id`, get the name of the `Scale` etc. How would I set this up without having another model/table for `Scale`?

**Edit**
To Clarify, I would like an `Item`s table, and a second `item_scale` table that would have a `item_id` column and a `scale_id` column. Then that `scale_id` will be a property (or, if necessary, a model/object) that I can reference from the `Item` model in NestJS.

Comment: What is the database you are using?

Comment: @fujy PostgreSQL

Answer (score 0):

One solution is the one you already mentioned to have a separate table for this `scale` and its mapping to `item` records. But if you really see that these `scale` values are not going to change that much through the application lifetime, and even if it happens it won't be through the user frontend, you can make use of the PostgreSQL [enumerated types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-enum.html) that is also supported in TypeORM

Example:

```
export enum Scale {
  small = 's',
  medium = 'm',
  large = 'l',
  xlarge = 'xl',
  ...
  // what ever other values that you have 
}

export class Item {
  @PrimaryColumn()
  id: string;

  @Column({ type: 'enum', enum: Scale })
  scale: Scale
}
```

This will define a new enumerated type with defined values only in your database, you can see that in the generated SQL that will look like this

```
CREATE TYPE "public"."item_scale_enum" AS ENUM (
  's', 'm', 'l', 'xl', ... 
)
```

Then when inserting a new `Item` record, only these values will be valid, any other will cause a database error. And of course, you can easily query item where scale = any of the defined values.

Comment: I've tended to avoid enums in databases (at least MySQL) as I was taught they're usually more trouble than they're worth. I can give this a try, except I was hoping to avoid having a "scale" value on the item table itself, as only a fraction of items will have a scale. I'll have most items with a "null" value, and I'd rather avoid that.

Comment: Define the troubles that you could face, and check if they exist or not in your use case.

Comment: And there is no problem with having null values in this column, you can deal with it like any other column with string contents.

Comment: there are lots of articles out there on why not to use enums in the database, and off topic for my question. With your approach I could just store an integer in the table and use an enum in NestJS. Ideally I'd prefer to not have extraneous columns in my tables as well. I hope there's a way to achieve this in NestJS

Comment: NestJS has nothing to do with your question that is about how you define your database schema.
And if you just put a number in your database, you would be missing the mapping between the number and its real value inside the database. If you want to store a number, then make that number an `id` for constants table approach. at least your database would know about the mapping.
Enums could be bad in some cases, but do you have any of these cases in your application?, that is your call.

Comment: It is, how do I do what I am asking in NestJS/TypeORM? I know how to set it up in PHP frameworks, I just cannot figure out how to do it in NestJS/TypeORM